# Associative table with date

Tags: mysql, database

In my application I have association between two entities employees and work-groups.
This association usually changes over time, so in my DB I have something like:

**emplyees**

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID | NAME |
| ...         | ...  |
```

**workgroups**

```
| GROUP_ID    | NAME |
| ...         | ...  |
```

**emplyees_workgroups**

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID | GROUP_ID | DATE  |
| ...         | ...      | ...   |
```

So suppose I have an association between employee 1 and group 1, valid from `2014-01-01` on.
When a new association is created, for example from `2014-02-01` on, the old one is no longer valid.

This structure for the associative table is a bit problematic for queries, but I actually would avoid to add an `END_DATE` field to the table beacuse it will be a reduntant value and also requires the execution of an insert + update or update on two rows every time a change happens in an association.

So have you any idea to create a more practical architecture to solve my problem? Is this the better approach?

Comment: I suspect that your existing structure is just fine. However, I think a more thorough example would be easier to contemplate. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. And presumably an employee can only be associated with one group at a time?

Comment: _“This structure for the associative table is a bit problematic for queries”_ – a bit … maybe – but it shouldn’t be _too_ problematic for common use cases. Or do you have queries in mind already where you would run into unsolvable problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what is called a slowly changing dimension.  That means that you need to have dates in the `employees_workgroup` table in order to find the right workgroup at the right time for a set of employees.

The best way to handle this is to have to dates, which I often call `effdate` and `enddate` on each row.  This greatly simplifies queries, where you are trying to find the workgroup at a particular point in time.  Such a query might look like with this structure:

```
select ew.*
from employees_workgroup ew
where MYDATE between effdate and enddate;
```

Now consider the same results using only one date per field.  It might be something like this:

```
  select ew.*,
  from employees_workgroup ew join
       (select employee_id, max(date) as maxdate
        from employees_workgroup ew2
        where ew2.employee_id = ew.employee_id and
              ew2.date <= MYDATE
       ) as rec
       on ew.employee_id = rec.employee_id and ew.adte = ew.maxdate;
```

The expense of doing an `update` along with the `insert` is minimal compared to the complexity this will introduce in the queries.